# How do I open the boot menu?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I want to uninstall 12.04 and install Ubuntu 13.04 instead.

When I was installing Ubuntu 12.04 from Windows 7 opened the boot menu <kbd>F12</kbd>.

I have read that on Ubuntu to enter the boot menu I have to press F2 or Fn-F2. I have tried both ways but it still doesn't open the boot menu.

So, how can I open the boot menu on Ubuntu 12.04?

Note: I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad X120e.

Comment: The BIOS exists outside of and before any OS, so there is no "on Ubuntu" part to entering the BIOS.

Comment: For me all you have to do is the moment you turn on the machine keep pressing shift to you come to a menu that says *ubuntu advanced options for ubuntu
you want the advanced option then click recovery mode it will then all you have to do is click down to root and there you go

Answer (score 2):

This from Lenovo:

While the "To interrupt normal startup, press Enter" message is displayed at the lower-left area of the screen, press the <kbd>F1</kbd> key. The BIOS Setup Utility menu will be displayed. If a password prompt appears, type the correct password.

Answer (score 0):

BIOS doesn't depend upon the OS. So OS has nothing to do with BIOS loading and there won't be any change to the key.

BIOS is a basic utility which initializes the hardwares and ask processor to execute instruction as stored in the first block of the hard disk. It doesn't what is in there in the hard disk, it just points CPU to there.

Now the first block of harddisk contain the information about OS, the loader. Which is GRUB in this case.Installing ubuntu  doesn't affect BIOS.

Consult your laptop manual to know the right key for BIOS. For lenevo F1 is set for BIOS utility in general. Keep pressing that key untill you get into BIOS.